# mumble: how do I send people to AFK after X minutes of not doing anything?

Tags: automation, administrator, mumble

How can I set up my Mumble server to automatically send people to the AFK channel after they have been inactive for X minutes?

Comment: This should be on Server Fault.

Comment: @Nitrodist: please don't just say a question should be on another SO/SF/SU trilogy site; you should also inform new users that questions can be migrated between the sites, and that they shouldn't crosspost.

Comment: please don't crosspost.  i'm not sure if Mumble questions are appropriate for Server Fault, but they might be.  if you want us to go ahead and migrate it for you, please flag for moderator attention and request it.  thanks!

Comment: No, mumble is not appropriate for Server Fault... I'm just running it from my home PC like most mumble users... not exactly a professional quality program.

Comment: @quackquixote Well, how do you flag it for migration? I am also sharing the view that this should be an SF question, as it clearly has to do with server config. Also, as little as I know of mumble, you might be required to do some scripting. Unfortunately, mumble uses [ZeroC Ice](http://www.zeroc.com/) for that. Which is quite complex for simple scripting.

Answer (score 1):

This post probably does belong on server fault rather than on superuser. Even if you feel like an end user, you're still running a server application that clients are connecting to.

**That being said**, the solution to the problem is to utilize MuMo (Mumble Moderator), which allows Python scripting to interact with the Mumble server, reducing the expertise requirement for simple server moderation to a minimum.

The latest version also includes a script for automatically shoving AFK users into a specified "idling" channel.

http://wiki.mumble.info/wiki/Mumo